# How and who does the code factoring/splitting of client and server code that are present in the same PHP file?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, client-server

Suppose, I have a PHP file present on server that contains some text, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and PHP code.

As per my knowledge any PHP code is executed on server side upon receiving the request for the same PHP file from client(i.e. the web browser).

Rest of the code from the PHP file i.e. HTML, CSS and JavaScript code are executed on client side(i.e. in web browser). In other words it's the job of web browser to execute such code on client side itself.

My question is all the things(i.e. the text, HTML, CSS, JavaScript, and PHP code) are present in the same file that has PHP extension and this file starts execution only upon receiving request for same file from client.

Then, after receiving the request how does the code separation is done and who does it?

By separation, I mean the separation of server side code and client side code. Who and how does this code separation takes place?

Also, in the end I get result of all the code on one single page(i.e. the PHP file I requested). Who and how does this re-combination of output of server and client side code in one single file?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is run on the server, which outputs **only content** (html, css, javascript, images - **whatever isn't php, or is produced by the php code**) to the client. All of which are to be handled by the client upon receiving - html and css will be parsed and displayed, javascript will be executed, and every other content handled in its own way. You may see each request from the client in your browser development tools, as well as the server response (each of which has a mimetype, meaning it only has one kind of content). A full, standard webpage usually is sent across several requests, the main html body being only the first of them.

Comment: Do you mean upon receiving the request at server from the client first of all PHP code gets executed and the non-php content(html, css, javascript, images - whatever isn't php, or is produced by the php code) is sent back to the browser in response? Until the PHP processed response is received at browser end no HTML, CSS, JavaScript, etc. will get parsed/executed? Does server side code executes first and then rest of everything i.e. html, css, javascript, images - whatever isn't php, or is produced by the php code?

Comment: Pretty much, one server request = one type of content sent back to the client. If that content is dynamic (php code), php gets executed along the way and can alter the response at will, otherwise the content is just sent as-is (the server adds a mimetype describing the type of the content, but that's about it). Each content is then received and parsed by the client and may trigger subsequent requests for additional content (js, images, css, video, you name it), which in turn may be dynamic as well, etc.